# What's the difference between actually click a button and the InvokeOnClick() method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, click

I wanna change a widget's backcolor at a appropriate point with the statement below:

```
IpAddressTextEdit.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
```

After trying many approaches, it finally works when I put this into a button_click event method and actually click the button physically. Just like below:

```
public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IpAddressTextEdit.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
    Console.WriteLine("Button 3 is clicked ! ");
}
```

But, I never want to do this via a click and it doesnt work when I invoke this click by using InvokeOnClick() at somewhere else. Even my debugger indicates that this statement has been executed, and the assignment is successful, the "Button 3 is clicked !" is also printed, all is going as same as actual click. The only difference is my widget doesnt change its color.

I can guess there're some mechanisms behind and debugger wont show me. This assignment just stay background and never impact the front UI. So what is the real difference btw InvokeOnClick and actual click. What should I do to make it work.

code of InvokeOnClick():

```
           if (TcpSocket.Connected)
           {
               MainForm mf = new MainForm();                    
               SettingsControl sc = new SettingsControl();                    
               sc.IpAddressTextEdit.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen; // assign directly
               mf.InvokeOnClick(sc.button3, EventArgs.Empty);     // Invoke a btn click
                    sc.OnSocketConnectedEventHandler(EventArgs.Empty); // raise a event create by my own                   

               if(!SocketRecvThread.IsAlive)
                       SocketRecvThread.Start();      //Begin receive;                    
               mf.SetupLeakDetector();  //Send command to setup machine

           }
```

As can be seen, I've try approaches including assign the color directly, invoke a event that create by my own, invoke a btnclick event. None of them work.

Comment: Show us the code that is calling the `InvokeOnClick` method.

Comment: Hi, is there a specific reason why you need to "fake" the clicking of the button instead of simply calling a method ?

Comment: thank you ! @PatrickHofman,  code is added,

Comment: @LucMorin， Hi, yes, as the code i just added, just calling a method doesnt work, so I am trying something else to make it work.

Comment: What is `SettingsControl` ? I'm assuming a custom control, but I don't see where you actually add it to a form. Also, that code snippet, where does it belong ? We need to understand the "structure" of your program in order to understand why `InvokeOnClick` is not giving you the expected result.

Comment: call `Application.DoEvents()` after calling `InvokeOnClick` and see if the problem resolve. **Warning: this is not the recommended way to solve the problem**

Comment: @LucMorin SettingsControl is a class declarate as  public partial class SettingsControl : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl. to contain method called by any user interface event, and some event handle setup. Sorry for any confusion,

Comment: @dotctor thank you, but this doesnt help.

Comment: You create new mf form, but I do not see a place where You show it to the user.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek , all codes of invokeonclick a attached lay in MainForm class , I new a MainForm mf because the compiler tells me a object reference is needed...

Comment: You create new MainForm and so have two main forms. But one is not visible. And You set color of IpAddressTextEdit that is on the form, that is not visible. How could You possibly see it?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek this helps!. The widget that I wanna change belong to SettingsControl calss, as you can see above, I create a new SettingsControl sc, and try all kinds of setting color on it. ... finally, I solved it .

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the behaviour the only difference I can see is the **timinig**. So what is the difference between setting backgroundcolor before or after the form is shown? Well you got some events to inspect, Like **Form_Load**, **Form_Shown** or **Form_Activate**. If the backgroundcolor of your textbox is set in any of these events (or in methods called in these events) it will overwrite what you have set before calling .Show() / .ShowDialog() on your form

[Complete list of events when a form is shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.But i dont think it is about overwrite. I found one more difference, it is, when actually click(and stop runtime by breakpoint) the value of EventArgs e is {X=40,Y=22 Button = left} which are sth about of my physical click, but it is null when invokeonclick(). So far, Maybe I could  get it via completely imitate a mouse click, or understand .net winform better and do it in a more proper way. Maybe you can see I am a kind of beginner, but still wanna find a directly way to solve the issue in front of me.

Comment: I dont think the matter is the difference btw click and "fake invoke" any more. instead, the matter is where I call the method contain the backcolor assign statement. As my tries, it works well when i call it in the SettingsControl class, which contain all methods called by UI event. But all codes about data recv, send, socket connection are in MainForm class. but I just want turn the edit box green when connect successfully.